# Can photons excert radiation pressure after negative interference?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, interference, coherence

### Motivation: understanding the EMDrive

In the context of speculating how the [EMDrive radio frequency resonant cavity thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF_resonant_cavity_thruster) may work, in case it turns out to do that, there is one point that really confuses me.

I understand that one approach to explain how it creates momentum is as follows:

### What is left from negative interference?

The cavity expels microwave photons in one direction - but they can not be detected because they are expelled as pairs which interfere negatively. I assume they are coherent.

Now, if I get it right, a beam of photons could exert radiation pressure to some solid object in it's way.

But is this true for a beam of negatively interfering photons?
Somehow that makes no sense to me, if I think of an electromagnetic wave of zero amplitude.
This is actually the core of my question.

### Can momentum created by "nothing", the result of negative interference?

Closely related, in the context of the EMDrive, the interesting point is that I assume that the beam can not cause momentum, if it can not cause radiation pressure.

Is there just some important factor I do not see?

Comment: If you eject "two photons that interfere negatively" I assume you mean they cancel. In that case, there is no energy, no momentum. You can _temporarily_ have zero amplitude (for example when two waves travel in opposite directions - zero amplitude, but large velocity) but not for photons traveling in the same direction. Note that "non mainstream science" is a reason for closing questions around here...

Comment: What is "negative interference"??? The EMDrive simply violates momentum conservation and that's that. Mount one of these on a skateboard, put it on the floor and make it go in a straight line for a hundred meters and show me that it hasn't lost any mass during that run. That is the proof that it works, no matter what the innards are.

Comment: @CuriousOne I was thinking of canceling out, while traveling in the same direction, with a phase shift of half the wave length. That seems to be the part that does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work because of Noether's theorem. Now, when am I going to get to see one mounted a skateboard? After all, I am being told that these things can move us trough the solar system... and, yet, they can't even seem to move a toy on the floor.

Comment: @CuriousOne i think youre not familiar with the EMdrive experiment. The forces (allegedly) generated are TINY and wouldnt move a skateboard if it turns out being physically realizeable and reproducible. Also note that one cannot say an experiment is invalid if it violates a theory. Theories have to be consistent with experiments...experimental results arent required to be consistent with previous theories. It just takes one reproducible, verifiable experiment to rewrite any applicable theory....

Comment: @user122066: I am familiar with end runs around Noether's theorem since the middle ages (for energy conservation) and  Rudolf Erich Raspe's Baron Munchausen (for momentum conservation). The problem with bold claims is that they demand bold proof, which those who claim that the EMDrive generates such an effect don't have. They do fit the pattern of "the next device will be much better", though, which is very widespread in the perpetual motion business. How about we get to see a flying saucer _now_?

Comment: @Floris I absolutely assume mainstream science.  My assumption of coherence, but with a phase shift, seems to be the point that makes no sense.

Comment: @CuriousOne EMdrive doesnt have anything to do with flying saucers or perpetual motion.  It's simply an experiment where a force is allegedly generated yet the experimenters and theorists have yet to determine where the force is coming from or even if the force is due to the system or the background.  Thats what we do in experimental physics.....we perform experiments and analyze the results carefully and look for a theory which explains the results.  If the results violate established theories then we look for independent reproduction of the experiment and ask the community to rip apart the e

Comment: @CuriousOne I think the idea is it does loose mass, equivalent to the energy of the photons that are expelled. That's not enough for a skateboard, or even a hoverboard in air, of course. Note that the experiments cause the microwave source to melt down after short time.

Comment: If the experimentals results turn out to be reality then theories get rewritten. Thats all. No big deal. Odds are the EMdrive forces are some kind of background effect that hasnt been pinned down. It certainly makes for an interesting topic in physics and the solution of the EMdrive whether positive or negative will be very illuminating.  It's just an interesting conundrum.  No biggy

Comment: There are no expelled photons here and if there were (e.g. by thermal radiation), the resulting force would be far too small. One doesn't need a dedicated research program to build a photon rocket, though, a light bulb with a simple aluminum reflector (a $10 value on a well known internet site) will do that just fine. As for the theorists... they don't have to do anything until the "experimenters" (cough) get their act together and publish a reproducible (and reproduced) precision result. And that, I predict, will never happen.

Comment: The EMDrive folks got it all wrong, of course, the optimal design looks like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k14WrS9d8f8 (at about 1:30+ into the episode). :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne It's not that I'm saying the EMDrive works; It's that I do not understand how their explanation could work out - but for the wrong reason, it seems. Maybe I should delete this and ask two separate questions instead, as to not pollute the interesting part about coherence, interference and momentum with the term EMDrive.

Comment: @CuriousOne exactly. It's very unlikely to be reproducible though maybe it has been reproduced? Even if it is reproducible i agree that it is extremely unlikely that it will be due to violation of current theories of physics as EM is very well understood despite its nonlinearities. Im not familiar with the current state of progress with this project. All i know is a lot of smart people were stumped and that physical experiments have a theoretical explanation. But that certainly doesnt mean the experiment should not be studied or that questions should not be asked.

Comment: @CuriousOne I admit, though, that the device is interesting. I'm going with the results of the German experiments: they concluded that the data they gathered was very interesting, but could not conclude whether it's an effect, or just very interesting noise...

Comment: You don't need a scientific explanation for something that isn't happening. It's really that simple. There is no interesting question here and whatever you may ask about the device falls squarely outside of mainstream science.

Comment: @user122066: They have reproduced the results independently, mounted it on a skateboard now and it actually drives around? Where is the video? :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne Even when I am fully convinced that the EMDrive does just not work, I think questions that came up from thinking about it, while coming to this conclusion, can be perfectly valid questions. Do you disagree? I think I did not make it clear enough that the question is independent of the EMDrive. Especially it's not relevant whether it actually works. Is there a specific sentence in the question that made you think it's more closely related to the EMDrive, other than being the context in which the question came up? I'd love to edit it to clarify!

Comment: Is momentum conserved is a very valid scientific question and I applaud your efforts to design a precision experiment... but where is it? the EMDrive is not a precision experiment.

Comment: @CuriousOne So that is a very valid answer to my question! I expected the it's just me not getting it - not that it is unknown; I would love having the means to do experiments on it... Would you mind making it an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you emitted two photons then each photon would carry away a positive amount of energy.

This would consume energy from your fuel source (unless you want to sacrifice conservation of energy). Hence you would arrive at your destination with less mass than you departed with (unless you collect more fuel on your journey). It simply wouldn't be a reactionless drive, as it is claimed to be.

And again, this wouldn't explain that you sometimes get thrust in one direction and sometimes get thrust in the opposite direction and that the result depends on what you use to measure it.

It's like if I told you that I could make money in the stock market, but sometimes I lost money and sometimes I made money and sometimes I made an investment and some people reported that I won money while other people reported that I lost money on that same investment.

This would not inspire any confidence in the claim that I can make money, would it? You'd think the people checking weren't doing a good job, since they don't agree with each other, and you'd notice that even if they were correct I still sometimes lose money.

And it isn't a good idea to simply mash together science words and hope it explains something.

That's not how good science gets done. It simply isn't.

You also need to be very very careful when you claim something can't be detected. You should seriously be honest with yourself and ask how much room there is exactly between the things that don't exist and the things that can't be detected.

Comment: Well said. But "stick market"?

Comment: I absolutely thing that "reactionless" makes no sense in the first place, for a thruster. Also, it's clear that a photon leaving reduces the energy (or mass) of the device. I did not read much details about the EMDrive, but they seemed to say the leaving photons are paired such that the waves cancel out - and that confuses me; Does what is left from canceled out waves still have mass or energy? Especially that they seemed to cancel out not just locally, moving along in parallel. By now I think that this is just not possible, resolving my confusion.